# Converting json to java pojo

Tags: java, json, gson

Trying to convert json object to java pojo using several online tools to use GSON to populate the data and I get an error:

This is a sample of json object:

```
{
    "ENCUESTA": {
        "ALOJAMIENTO": {
            "RESIDENCIA": [
                {
                    "ID_PROVINCIA_ISLA": "ES511",
                    "MOVIMIENTO": [
                        {
                            "SALIDAS": 0,
                            "PERNOCTACIONES": 3,
                            "N_DIA": "08",
                            "ENTRADAS": 3
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "MOVIMIENTO": [
                        {
                            "SALIDAS": 0,
                            "PERNOCTACIONES": 3,
                            "N_DIA": "06",
                            "ENTRADAS": 3
                        }
                    ],
                    "ID_PAIS": "CHN"
                }
            ]
        },
        "CABECERA": {
            "FECHA_REFERENCIA": {
                "MES": 11,
                "ANYO": 2017
            },
            "NOMBRE_ESTABLECIMIENTO": "UNKNOWN"

        }
    }
}
```

RESIDENCIA can have two options (is xs:choice in xsd), so you can have:

```
MOVIMIENTO, ID_PROVINCIA_ISLA
```

or

```
MOVIMIENTO, ID_PAIS
```

When I generate the POJOs, I get just one of them depending which is first in the object:

```
public class RESIDENCIA
{
    private MOVIMIENTO[] MOVIMIENTO;

    private String ID_PROVINCIA_ISLA;
}
```

ID_PAIS is not present

```
public class MOVIMIENTO
{
    private String PERNOCTACIONES;

    private String N_DIA;

    private String SALIDAS;

    private String ENTRADAS;
}
```

My initial solution is just to add ID_PAIS, but GSON complains.....

```
public class RESIDENCIA {
    private MOVIMIENTO[] MOVIMIENTO;

    private String ID_PAIS;

    private String ID_PROVINCIA_ISLA;

}
```

Error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $.ENCUESTA.ALOJAMIENTO.RESIDENCIA[16].MOVIMIENTO

My process start with an xml file. Its converted to json using:

```
JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
<xs:element name="RESIDENCIA" id="ID_PAIS" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="ID_PAIS">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Codificación A3 de la ISO eliminando
                            España
                        </xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:length value="3" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ID_PROVINCIA_ISLA">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Codificación según ANEXO 4
                        </xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:length value="5" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="MOVIMIENTO" maxOccurs="31">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="N_DIA" type="N_DIAType" />
                        <xs:element name="ENTRADAS">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedLong">
                                    <xs:totalDigits value="4" />
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="SALIDAS">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedLong">
                                    <xs:totalDigits value="4" />
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="PERNOCTACIONES">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedLong">
                                    <xs:totalDigits value="4" />
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Any idea??
Thanks

Comment: yes, all of them

Answer (score 0):

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

suggests that the data about to be parsed is a JSON Object (enclosed within { } braces in JSON), but as per the RESIDENCIA Class defined by you, you expect the MOVIMIENTO to be an Array within the RESIDENCIA object.

Verify that the JSON string that you are trying to parse is uniformly created for all MOVIMIENTO related data occurrences.

> Path $.ENCUESTA.ALOJAMIENTO.RESIDENCIA[16].MOVIMIENTO

suggests that the RESIDENCIA object in question is at index 16.

Comment: Hi, its not defined by me, I'm using this tools: http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/   update question with xsd code

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(SampleObject.class, new SampleDeserializer()).create();

@Test
public void createGson() {
    String demoStr = "{\n" +
            "    \"ENCUESTA\": {\n" +
            "        \"ALOJAMIENTO\": {\n" +
            "            \"RESIDENCIA\": [\n" +
            "                {\n" +
            "                    \"ID_PROVINCIA_ISLA\": \"ES511\",\n" +
            "                    \"MOVIMIENTO\": [\n" +
            "                        {\n" +
            "                            \"SALIDAS\": 0,\n" +
            "                            \"PERNOCTACIONES\": 3,\n" +
            "                            \"N_DIA\": \"08\",\n" +
            "                            \"ENTRADAS\": 3\n" +
            "                        }\n" +
            "                    ]\n" +
            "                },\n" +
            "                {\n" +
            "                    \"MOVIMIENTO\": [\n" +
            "                        {\n" +
            "                            \"SALIDAS\": 0,\n" +
            "                            \"PERNOCTACIONES\": 3,\n" +
            "                            \"N_DIA\": \"06\",\n" +
            "                            \"ENTRADAS\": 3\n" +
            "                        }\n" +
            "                    ],\n" +
            "                    \"ID_PAIS\": \"CHN\"\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "            ]\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        \"CABECERA\": {\n" +
            "            \"FECHA_REFERENCIA\": {\n" +
            "                \"MES\": 11,\n" +
            "                \"ANYO\": 2017\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            \"NOMBRE_ESTABLECIMIENTO\": \"UNKNOWN\"\n" +
            "\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}";
    SampleObject sampleObject = gson.fromJson(demoStr, SampleObject.class);
    System.out.println(sampleObject);
}
```

And the Deserializer

```
public class SampleDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<SampleObject> {
    @Override
    public SampleObject deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext)
            throws JsonParseException {
        SampleObject sampleObject = new SampleObject();
        SampleObject.Encuesta encuestaObject = new SampleObject.Encuesta();
        SampleObject.ALOJAMIENTO alojamientoObject = new SampleObject.ALOJAMIENTO();

        List<ResidenciaBase> baseList = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonObject encuesta = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("ENCUESTA");
        JsonObject alojamiento = encuesta.getAsJsonObject("ALOJAMIENTO");
        JsonArray residencia = alojamiento.getAsJsonArray("RESIDENCIA");

        for (JsonElement element : residencia) {
            if (element.getAsJsonObject().has("ID_PROVINCIA_ISLA")) {
                ResidenciaProv prov = new Gson().fromJson(element.getAsJsonObject().toString(), ResidenciaProv.class);
                baseList.add(prov);
            }
            if (element.getAsJsonObject().has("ID_PAIS")) {
                ResidenciaPais residenciaPais = new Gson().fromJson(element.getAsJsonObject().toString(), ResidenciaPais.class);
                baseList.add(residenciaPais);
            }
        }
        alojamientoObject.setResidencia(baseList);
        encuestaObject.setAlojamiento(alojamientoObject);

        JsonObject cabecera = encuesta.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("CABECERA");
        SampleObject.Cabecera cabecera1 = new Gson().fromJson(cabecera.toString(), SampleObject.Cabecera.class);
        encuestaObject.setCabecera(cabecera1);
        sampleObject.setEncuesta(encuestaObject);
        return sampleObject;
    }
}
```

And all entity define, you can check [here](https://github.com/einverne/jutils/commit/89ea3ae2f07ee9c1239c514dbecf16964caa7bdd)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it